# Bootstrap btn-primary button unintended hover color and effect. How do I override this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure what's causing my `Bootstrap` primary buttons to act this way. When I hover over, it turns completely white like this:
[image: Button turns white on hover]

Other `btn-primary` buttons act normally, it's just these two buttons in the header that's causing the problem.

I do not have any custom `CSS` rules regarding the hover effect. I haven't figured out where it's coming from so I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Please do post your codes in your question.

Comment: You can see where the rule is coming from using the browser's dev tool or firebug open while hovering

Comment: @LelioFaieta Please show markup of your `nav` or another container with these buttons.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov what are you talking about?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Sorry, it was addressed to Henry Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is happeing to these buttons using browser built-in dev tools.This should make you find the right answer. If not, just specify a rule for `.btn-primary` in `header` div, just like:

```
#header > .btn-primary {
    ...
}
```

Next time post some code or an URL, so we can see what are you exactly talking about, bro.